# Slow upload speed using Symfony2 - Nginx. 100 MB in 15 minutes

Tags: performance, symfony, nginx, file-upload

I have a form in Symfony 2.7 to upload videos between 100MB - 500 MB to my web. The upload speed is around 700 kbps so a 100MB video last more than 15 minutes to be uploaded. This is too much, users run out of my website! I’ve tried with Wetransfer and the same video last only 30 seconds to upload with an upload speed of 30Mbps. (wetransfer upload speed is more than 30 times higher!)

I have a digitalocean VPS, nginx, symfony2.7 application.

I have been reading a lot of Nginx configuration and testing diferents configs but the speed remain very low. I have done changes in php.ini, nginx.conf but I don't understand what is happening..

This is my vps speed:

```
~$ curl -s  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -

Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from DigitalOcean (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Citybridge (New York City, NY) [16.98 km]: 2.628 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 380.93 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed....................................................................................................
Upload: 352.91 Mbit/s
```

Nginx.conf and sites-available/domain:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
   }

http {
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
    client_body_buffer_size 32M;
    proxy_buffer_size 32M;
    proxy_buffers 16 8M;
    client_header_buffer_size 16k;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 16k;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml     text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.*****.org;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/***.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/***.org/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers *****;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    root /var/www/****/web;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (libwww-perl) ) {
       return 403;
     }
location ~ /.well-know{
    allow all;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/***.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/***.log;

location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 1d;
}
}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is either nginx configuration, network routing issues or simply bad code. Try to run `php bin/console server:run --env=prod 0.0.0.0:8000`  and open port `8000` on your server temporarily. Then try uploading using the php server. If the speed is better - then you need to fix your nginx configuration. It would be helpful if you post your full nginx config for that domain and some code, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! The website is under ssl protocol. with letsencrypt. I'm going to update the full nginx.config file. The php code is a simple form in symfony to attach a file.

Comment: How can I open the port 8000 temporarily? Can I try it if the site has https protocol?

Comment: Are you storing the file directly to the filesystem or in the database? As for the port - you should check your provider's "how to". You could do it with `iptables`, but if you don't know what you're doing you might get yourself locked out. Better ask the support to do it for you.

Comment: I upload the file with a symfony form. In the database I store tha name of the file and in the file is saved in a folder of a vps.

Comment: Well in that case it's nginx configuration or network routing issues (between you and the hosting). Try setting `proxy_buffering off;`  in your config and (possibly) comment out the buffers you've configured.

Comment: I have comment out the buffers and adding proxy_buffering off; to my nginx.conf but the upload speed is the same (<1Mbps) (with wetransfer I have >30Mbps). The hosting is a VPS with digitalocean. How can I check if there are some problems there?

Comment: Ask DigitalOcean for help. I don't know what's the problem here. They might have a shaper which is limiting the upload speed.

Comment: Thank you tftd. I'm going to ask to Digitaocean